# Proving transitivity with Power Set Relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I have this question and am having trouble proving transitivity for this:

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $\sim_n$ be the relation on $\mathcal{P}([n])$ specified by $A \sim_n B$ if and only
if $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$. Determine, with proof, all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sim_n$ is an equivalence relation.

I am trying to separate it into four cases since for some $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$  and assume $(x,y), (y,z) \in R$. Let $A = \mathcal{P}([x]), B = \mathcal{P}([y]), C = \mathcal{P}([z])$. This would imply that $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$ and $B \subseteq C$ or $C \subseteq B$. I am having trouble proving the cases where 1. $A \subseteq B$ and $C \subseteq B$ and 2.  $B \subseteq A$ and $B \subseteq C$. How do we prove that $A \subseteq C$ or $C \subseteq A$ in these cases?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are elements of $\mathcal{P}([n])$ in your defintion of the relation $\sim_n$, why are you taking "$A = \mathcal{P}([x]), B = \mathcal{P}([y]), C = \mathcal{P}([z])$"? And what is $R$

Comment: I may be misinterpreting the question but I thought A was the set for some n in the natural numbers and B is a set for some n2 in the natural numbers (these sets would be represented by the power set in this case). R I defined as the relation itself. Maybe I am getting this totally wrong though.

Comment: No the relation is $\sim_n$ and it is defined on the power set, $\mathcal{P}([n])$, of $[n]$, which is the set of all subsets of $[n]$. $A$ and $B$ in the defintion are elements of $\mathcal{P}([n])$, and hence are subsets of $[n]$

Comment: Oh I see, but I'm pretty sure that I am supposed to prove that for all n in the naturals that this is an equivalence relation. Yet, you say it cant be for any n > 1. Can you go through the proof (ie Reflexive, Symmetric, and Transitive?)

Comment: It cannot be transitive is for sure. So no need to check the other properties. Although of cource $A\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq B\implies B\supseteq A $. Hence the relation is both symmetric and reflexive.

Answer (score 1):

There can be no $n>1$, for which $\sim_n$ is an equivalence relation, precisely because they would not satisfy transitivity. Because take $A=\{1,2,\cdots,k\},B=\{k+1,\cdots,n\}$, and $C=[n]$. Then $A\sim_n C$, and $B\sim_n C$, but $A\not\sim_n B$, because $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.